# Google Maps API V3 - Highlight a single road/street

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to highlight a specified road or street using Google Maps API V3?

Here is an example of what I am trying to get (image from searching a place in google): [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUW1r.png)

Styled maps does not do what I want since it will apply to all roads. Polylines is an option but finding the coordinates can be a bit of a pain since they are not always complete.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [highlight a list of streets on a map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356540/highlight-a-list-of-streets-on-a-map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has already been discussed and I'm afraid you'll have to use polylines.

This might be useful though : [Highlighting whole street with some maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155032/highlighting-whole-street-with-some-maps-api#answer-2155074)

Comment: Thanks for this! Snapping to a road using the directions service isn't the best solution when one-way streets are involved. I guess it will have to do.